# Reduce UI load when instantiating several Views in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel

My setup is simplified like this:

My main window consists only of a `ContentPresenter` and every visual thing is a `View` filled with data from a `ViewModel` linked by a set of `DataTemplate`s assigning each `ViewModel` to a specific `View`.

The `View`s also contain `ContentPresenter`s and `ItemControl`s to display nested `ViewModel`s.

You can think of the main window as "display each file and folder recursively starting from this folder" and there are `View`s/`ViewModel`s for files and folders.

I preload the `ViewModel` in a background thread and display a "loading" message in the main window (the main window is responsive albeit you cannot do anything anyway).

After the `ViewModel`s are all created, I marshall the swapping of the DataContext.

Until the `View`s are all fully loaded, the main window freezes for approx. 2 seconds.

Profiling the application doesn't show this time, most likely because it's done in some WPF core that is not profiled.

**Is there a way to "preload/prerender" the `View`s without blocking the UI?**

I know that when the application is not showing anything while being blocked this may not be of concern in this concrete case. But there are similar cases where there is something useful displayed.

Comment: You described my project almost to a T.  On startup, I use background workers to create my viewmodels and load all data from a database.  It takes a while, so I use the background worker to update a progress spinner while the data is loading.  I don't know of any way to preload/prerender the views, especially since the viewmodels haven't been created yet for the views to bind to.  In some cases, my individual views also have their own progress spinners if they still need time to load after the main window has loaded.

Comment: @NielW: So if all the views are available, what's the point in creating the views one after another? Instead of one large blocking period, I have several smaller in succession (probably taking longer in total)? I also experienced that if I create some stuff collapsed (some views contain `Expander`s) the blocking time is reduced but the time saved is required later on when the item is expanded the first time...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Your app has to take the time to load anything in the Visual Tree.  If you don't want it to load, don't add it to the visual tree until you're ready to take the time (don't instantiate your view models).  I have some views that have their own progress spinners, and they load while the rest of the app stays responsive and useable.  So you only block when you absolutely have to.

Comment: I assume there is no way to build the views in a non UI-thread? I already found out that if you have a `Brush` for instance defined in a view model, it must be freezed if it was created in a non UI thread. If I pause execution while the app is blocked, the app is in external code for the UI thread (and the other threads also). So I assume a loading animation wouldn't be animated...

Comment: @NielW: The total amount of ViewModels should be roughly 2000, nested in up to 10 levels. I use a lot of borders with semi transparent background and/or gradients. Maybe you could provide me a link to some project also using "our" approach which performs well. Maybe I can find the relevant difference...

Comment: I built mine from the ground up this way.  I just assumed it was how all MVVM projects were organized.  Sorry I don't have more info for you.